# Not available native resolution 2560x1440 (Display: DELL U2515H, GPU: nVidia GF550Ti, Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 15.04, hdmi, xrandr

My display is a `DELL U2515H`. I have a `nVidia GF550Ti` GPU, and both should support the native resolution of `2560 x 1440` over HDMI. But highest resolution ubuntu detected automatically is `2048 x 1152`.

Tested solution "A" (unsuccessful):

1. The command `cvt 2560 1440 40` gives me

   ```
   2560x1440 39.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 58.98 kHz; pclk: 201.00 MHz
   Modeline "2560x1440_40.00"  201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 -hsync +vsync
   ```
2. And `sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_40.00"  201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 -hsync +vsync` gives nothing back, so I expect it works.
3. Finally, `sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1440_40.00`

   ```
   X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

   Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
   Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
   Serial number of failed request:  29
   Current serial number in output stream:  30
   ```

Comment: Additional info: my GPU Driver = NVIDIA binary driver, ver 340.76

Comment: Additional info: GPU driver upgraded to version 346.59, and problem still remains

Comment: What refresh rate and do you have a `monitors.xml` file?  If yes, please post to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Whats the output of `xrandr | grep "connected"`

Answer (score 4):

[Official answer on a dell forum.](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19641517)

Says "A maximum resolution of 2048 x 1152 through the U2515H HDMI in means that the signal it is getting from the video card is not HDMI 1.4. It is HDMI 1.3. Which is why you are getting 2048 x 1152."

You might want to check the spec on your GPU, to see what version of HDMI it supports.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please don't add links to Amazon, as this might be seen as SPAM. Any external link might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @MichelleHine Nice first answer! We like to avoid any external links, except as reference, so if you can try to include everything important from the link it makes it much better! Also, one small point to bear in mind that this isn't really a forum, it's a Q&A. We like to make that clear because Answers should be answers not responses - like you've done here really well. The [tour] should clarify a bit. Finally, the last comment has some really good info - if you [edit] it into your post more people will see it, and you may get more upvotes. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice Fabby and Tim....entry edited to give one clear answer and a link for reference.

Comment: I've just received the same monitor, and can confirm it does work at 2560 x 1440 over HDMI on Ubuntu (14.04 with Unity), straight out the box...but my MB specifically says HDMI ver 1.4a supported.....sorry this doesn't help you though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same monitor. In my case it was the cable, which was not able to serve a resolution higher than 2048x1152p. Make sure you use a cable that is capable to serve such a high resolution.