# 2560x1080 resolution in Ubuntu 16.04 with opensource ATI driver

Tags: drivers, hdmi, display-resolution, xrandr, amd-graphics

I am trying to get my new 21:9 monitor to work with Ubuntu 16.04. So far I've tried using xrandr, but with little success. When i try to set it at 2560x1080 the screen glitches horribly and is unusable. The screen usually defaults to 1920x1080.

The closest thing I've found on the internet was using it at 2160x912. I'm using a ATI 6950 via HDMI and stock opensource driver. I've tried upgrading the kernel to 4.8 and 4.9 but still no luck. Also tried an HDMI -> DVI adapter. Still nothing.

I've also tried upgrading and it still didn't do the trick.

Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia says that some cards of the [Radeon 6000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_6000_Series) support HDMI 1.4, my guess is that others only support 1.3. DVI is even worse at supporting high resolutions. Check if the card supports  HDMI 1.4 and that HDMI the cable supports is too (if i doubt try another – certified – cable not longer than 2 meters). Use DisplayPort if possible or get a newer card. I was able to make [2560x1440 work on 30Hz](http://askubuntu.com/q/584287/40581) but it's no fun.